# prevent d3.behaviour.zoom jumping

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've got a small application with different `tools` within it. Two of these tools use the mousewheel, but in different ways, and I'm finding they incorrectly interacting with each other at the moment. I'm wondering if there's a way I can prevent this.

I'll provide a simplified noddy example which demonstrates the affect. If you run the snippet (click the SVG background/circle before starting) you should be able to zoom with a mousewheel.

If however you hold down a key (to simulate using a different tool) then the mousewheel delta gets logged instead of zooming. If you then attempt to zoom without a key pressed, the zoom jumps based on the mousewheel changes from when the key was pressed.

I've included an animated gif to demonstrate, how the zoom jumps massively when I try to use the `d3.behaviour.zoom` after supressing it for a while. So my question is, is there a way I can change the `d3.behaviour.zoom` so it just behaves on the delta since the last operation, or is there a way for me to pause it's recording of scale to prevent this jumping?

[image]

```js
var keydown = false;

// Random circles
const circles = d3.range(1000).map(function() {
  return {
    x: Math.random() * 700,
    y: Math.random() * 400
  }
});

// Create the random data, just so we can see when we're zooming
d3.select(".view")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => d.x)
  .attr("cy", d => d.y)
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", "red")
  .style("pointer-events", "none");


// Create the D3 zoom and hook it up to the interaction layer
const zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
  .on("zoom", () => {
    if (!keydown) {
      d3.select(".view").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }
  });

d3.select(document)
  .on("keydown", () => {
    keydown = true;
  })
  .on("keyup", () => {
    keydown = false;
  });

d3.select("#interaction").call(zoom);

// Listen to the mousewheel somewhere else
d3.select("#interaction").on("mousewheel.test", () => {
  if (keydown) {
    console.log(d3.event.wheelDeltaY);
  }
});
```

```css
svg {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="700" height="400">
<g class="view">
   <rect id="interaction" x="0" y="0" width="700" height="400"></rect>
</g>
<svg>
```

:

```
export default class PanAndZoomTool extends Tool {

    constructor(toolManager) {
        // Create a zoom behavior to listen to events
        const zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                                .scaleExtent([minZoom, maxZoom])
                                .on("zoom", () => { this.zoomed(); })

        // Hook up the zoom behaviour
        d3.select(INTERACTION)
          .call(zoom);
    }

    /** Respond to the zoomed event on the interaction layer  */
    zoomed() {
        if(!this.isActive()) return;

        d3.select(VIEWPORT).attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working as expected for me (Chrome 58 on Windows 7 64bits). It's probably a good idea editing your question specifying in what browser/environment this behaviour happens.

Comment: @Gerado Furtado I'm using latest Chrome x64 on Windows 10